# How did Bombelli transform $\sqrt[3]{2\pm11\sqrt{-1}}$ into $2\pm\sqrt{-1}$?

Tags: algebra

The story of Bombelli solving the equation $x^3=15x+4$ in *L'Algebra* and introducing $\sqrt{-1}$ is well known. The equation, having obvious root $x=4$, is solved using Cardano's formula:
$$
x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{(\frac{q}{2})^2-(\frac{p}{3})^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{q}{2}-\sqrt{(\frac{q}{2})^2-(\frac{p}{3})^3}}
$$
getting $x=\sqrt[3]{2+11\sqrt{-1}}+\sqrt[3]{2-11\sqrt{-1}}$.

After that, all the accounts I've read so far merely check that
$$ (2+\sqrt{-1})^3=2+11\sqrt{-1} $$ and $$(2-\sqrt{-1})^3=2-11\sqrt{-1}$$
to conclude that the formula gives the correct answer $x=(2+\sqrt{-1})+(2-\sqrt{-1})=4$.

The question is: how did Bombelli transform $\sqrt[3]{2\pm11\sqrt{-1}}$ into $2\pm\sqrt{-1}$? Is it detailed in the book? Did he know a procedure to simplify $\sqrt[3]{m+n\sqrt{k}}$ in the form $a+b\sqrt{k}$ for positive $k$? Was this procedure exposed in earlier chapters of *L'Algebra*, or in other books of the time, in relation to Cardano's formula?

Comment: I believe that you meant to say $x^3=15x+4$ rather than $x^3+15x=4$. The short article [Bombelli and the Invention of Complex Numbers](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2006/12/bombelli-and-invention-of-complex.html) is devoted to the methods Bombelli used to transform one expression into the other.

Comment: You're right of course, I fixed the equation. I will look into the article.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bombelli did not have a general method for such transformation, nor does it exist. Doing so is equivalent to solving the [irreducible case of the cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis), which is impossible in (real) radicals. It is solvable in inverse trigonometric functions, as Vieta showed later, but simplifying his trigonometric expression is itself a chore.

However, when everything is an integer one can find the solutions by educated guessing. In this case, according to [Katz's History of Mathematics, 12.3.2](https://www.academia.edu/35397288/Rd_Edition_Victor_J._Katz_A_History_of_Mathema), Bombelli used indeterminates $a,b$ to set up (in modern notation)
$(a+\sqrt{-b})^3=2+11\sqrt{-1}$. Given his rules for $\sqrt{-1}$, this quickly leads to $(a-\sqrt{-b})^3=2-11\sqrt{-1}$, and then to 
$$a^2+b=5;\ \ a(a^2-3b)=2.$$
By simple divisibility considerations, there are only four choices for $a$, and Bombelli shows that $a=2$ is the only viable one, with $b=1$. Note that attempting to solve this "honestly" leads to another cubic $4a^3=15a+2$, no better than the original one.

[LaNave-Mazur's Reading Bombelli](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03025306) gives more insight into the way Bombelli handled cubics, and complex numbers that came up in them. As they note, Bombelli's "procedure" was generally not very tidy:

> "*if you open
>   Bombelli's treatise you discover nothing resembling complex
>   numbers until page 133, at which point certain mathematical
>   objects (that might be regarded by a modern as
>   "complex numbers") burst onto the scene, in hill battle array,
>   in the middle of an on-going discussion. Here is how
>   Bombelli introduces these mathematical objects. He writes,
>   "I have found another sort of cubic radical which behaves
>   in a very different way from the others"... Complex numbers, when they occur in Gerolamo Cardano's earlier treatise Ars Magna, occur neatly as quantities
>   like $2 + \sqrt{-15}$. But they appear initially in Bombelli's
>   treatise as cubic radicals of the type of quantities discussed
>   by Cardano; a somewhat complicated way for them to arise
>   in a treatise that is thought of as an organized exposition
>   of the formal properties of complex numbers!*"